# What does a note with a dot next to it mean?

Tags: theory, sheet-music

[image]

The book I'm going through doesn't seem to explain a lot of details. I'm looking at the next example of sheet music but the author doesn't mention or explain a note with a dot next to it.

Comment: Litterally [googled](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=What+does+a+note+with+a+dot+next+to+it+mean%3F) your question. Tons of explanations.

Comment: Sounds like a change of books may be on the cards!

Answer (score 3):

A dot following a note, as in your diagram, increases the length of the note by one half or 50%.  So without the dot it would be a quarter note (duration 2 eighth notes) and with the dot it is a quarter note plus an eighth note (duration 3 eighth notes).

As @arminb says you can google this and get lots of answers.